# Google cloud function returning before function is complete

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, subprocess, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

## Google cloud function is suddenly returning before function is complete.

1. This executer function is triggered by pubsub **A**.
2. Send **50** request to pubusb **A**.
3. Function **executer** run 50 requests one by one. But sometimes returned(finished) before show this message → `print("Published.")`*(this messages means function is completed)*

   - function memory is 2gb, maximum function instances are 40, timeout is 300sec
4. When complete this function will be publish to pubsub **B**.

**main.py**

```py
# function name is : executer

import os
import subprocess
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

def main(event):
    ...

    commands = event['commands']

    cmd_results = []
    for command in commands:
        print('Action execution started.')
        cmd_res = {}
        try:
            print("subprocess.run()")
            res = subprocess.run(
                command.split(" "),
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
            )

            print("returncode : " + str(res.returncode))
            print("result : " + str(res.stdout.decode()))
            cmd_res['returncode'] = res.returncode
            cmd_res['result'] = str(res.stdout.decode())

            cmd_results.append(cmd_res)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error : {}".format(e))

    print("Action exectution finished.")
    data = {
        "cmd_results": cmd_results,
        "id": 1,
    }

    # publish command result to pubsub 
    try:
        print("Publish to pubusb.")
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path("PROJECT_NAME", "TOPIC_NAME")
        publisher.publish(topic_path, data=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))
        print("Published.")
        return {'status': 200}
    except Exception as e:
        print("Pubsub error : {}".format(e))
```

**requirements.txt**

```
botocore
google-cloud-pubsub==0.39.1
```

[This is function log message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaiwZ.png)

Comment: What makes you say the function is returning before printing? Are you sure that you're not getting an exception? Using `except Exception` is going to catch every possible exception.

Comment: @DustinIngram Sure, doesnt't getting an exception. Returned wIthout any error or warning message. I uploaded function log messages under the question block.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce. What are the commands that the subprocess is running here?

Comment: @DustinIngram for example: commands=[`sleep 4`, `sleep 8`, `sleep 12`]

Comment: Those are the commands you're actually using? Or just an example? Is it possible all your commands together are exceeding the 300s timeout?

Comment: @DustinIngram those commands are just example. There isn't showing any error of timeout, coding error. Suddenly returning is it a timeout error ?

Comment: Can you specify which commands you are actually using? Is a difference between the ones that are being returned before they are completed?
Also your last comment is a bit confusing, can you rephrase what you meant?